# error while loading shared libraries: libX11.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in linux docker container

Tags: java, linux, docker, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to run my chromedriver selenium tests within my docker image (java).

ChromeDriver - linux 64

Here is my Dockerfile

```
# Dockerfile
FROM openjdk

ENV MAVEN_VERSION 3.3.9

RUN mkdir -p /usr/share/maven \
  && curl -fsSL http://apache.osuosl.org/maven/maven-3/$MAVEN_VERSION/binaries/apache-maven-$MAVEN_VERSION-bin.tar.gz \
    | tar -xzC /usr/share/maven --strip-components=1 \
  && ln -s /usr/share/maven/bin/mvn /usr/bin/mvn




ENV MAVEN_HOME /usr/share/maven

VOLUME /root/.m2

CMD ["mvn"]
```

After building the image, when i run the docker - i get the error while loading shared libraries: libX11.so.6: cannot open shared object file - though chromedriver is present in the root folder.

Answer (score 6):

For all practical purposes a docker container is a headless server, without an X11-server. Therefore docker images usually does not have the X11 libraries needed for graphical clients to run.

Either install them or use another Docker image which has them.